# Spring Boot Maven and MySQL Error Handling

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, maven, error-handling

I have the following Spring Boot MySQL query:

```
visitorrepository.save(newvisitor)
```

Upon execution of this MySQL query, I want to return a success JSON or failure JSON in the following format:

**Success State**:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Some Helpful Message",
    "data": { } //This would be the newvisitor JSON that includes the primary key (id)
}
```

**Failure State**:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Some Helpful Message",
    "error_code": "404", // This should be whatever error number was returned
    "data": { } //This would be the newvisitor JSON that does not include the primary key (id)
}
```

In angular the response is captured as follows

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/v1/api/post', this.visitor.value).toPromise().then((response:any) => { 
      console.log(response);
   })
```

post.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class post {

    @Autowired
    visitorrepository visitorrepository;

    @PostMapping("/v1/api/post")
    public void insert(@Valid @RequestBody newvisitor newvisitor) {
       try {
            visitorrepository.save(newvisitor);
            return // Success State JSON
        } catch () {
            return // Error State JSON
        }
    }
}
```

newvisitor.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "visitors")
public class newvisitor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Size(min=1, max=250)
    @NotBlank
    private String firstname;
    @NotBlank
    private String lastname;
    @NotBlank
    private String month;
    @NotBlank
    private String day;
    @NotBlank
    private String year;
    @NotBlank
    private String socialsecuritynumber;
    @NotBlank
    private String street1;
    private String street2;
    @NotBlank
    private String city;
    @NotBlank
    private String state;
    @NotBlank
    private String zip;
    @NotBlank
    private String phone;
    @Email
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    public newvisitor(){
        super();
    }
    public newvisitor(String firstname, String lastname, String month, String day, String year, String socialsecuritynumber, String street1, String street2, String city, String state, String zip, String phone, String email) {
        super();

        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
        this.socialsecuritynumber = socialsecuritynumber;
        this.street1 = street1;
        this.street2 = street2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

visitorrepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface visitorrepository extends CrudRepository<newvisitor, Long> {
}
```

The thought is to catch everything from MySQL database not connecting, to invalid data entry, to duplicate records, bascially anything that prevented the initial query visitorrepository.save(newvisitor) from working, and return this to angular as a JSON. I feel like ResponseEntity or RestControllerAdvice might be the answer, just not sure best way to implement if this is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer.

> I feel like ResponseEntity or RestControllerAdvice might be the answer

You only create a dto response with your format. then put it in ResponseEntity in case error or not.

Comment: I understand the objective with RestControllerAdvice, and ResponseEntity; objective being what they are ultimately accomplishing in theory, but when I have tried to play with the implementation I failed misserably. I need to understand the actual syntax implementation here. The examples I have followed online don't line-up in a way that I am able to follow and adjust as necessary. Thanks for taking a look.